# How to make the Opencart mini cart close when touched by iPhone/iPad user

Tags: opencart

I am making a responsive theme for opencart. When in iPhone view I can click on the cart and the contents drop down and show what is in the cart. The problem I am having is that I can't get the cart to close again so it stays open and in the way.

I managed to get it to work by changing 'mouseleave' to 'click' but it only works once, I then have to refresh the page to get it to work again. I'm sure this is very simple for someone.

Here is the code;

```
/* Ajax Cart */
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
    $('#cart').addClass('active');

    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

    $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I put something along the lines of this code above your pasted code in common.js to fix this issue.

```
$('html').on('touchend.tap', function(){
  if ($('#cart').hasClass('active')){
    $('#cart').removeClass('active')
  }
 });

$('div#cart').on('touchend.tap', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This allows the links to function within the minicart